# Bias of random variable

Tags: estimators

I have a really simple question of definition.

Consider that I have an estimator $\widehat{a}$ and a variable $a$.

I know that we define the bias of $\widehat{a}$ by $B(\widehat{a})=\mathbb{E}(\widehat{a})-a$.

I just want to know in the case where $a$ is a random variable, if the definition is this one:

$B(\widehat{a})=\mathbb{E}(\widehat{a})-\mathbb{E}(a)$.

Answer (score 1):

In the case $a$ is a random variable (r.v.) we distinguish between two types of unbiased: (hereinafter I'm switching to $\theta$ and $\hat{\theta}$ instead of $a$ and $\hat{a}$ respectively):

1. Unbiased in the strong sense: given by $E\left \{ \left (  \hat{\theta} - \theta \right )| \theta\right \} = 0, \quad \forall \theta$. Most often tha n not it is hard to satisfy this definition.
2. Unbiased  in the weak sense: given by $E\left \{  \hat{\theta} - \theta \right \} = 0, $ where the expectation is executed on all random terms inside. The meaning of this criterion is that you want the estimator to be unbiased "in the mean" and not for all values of $\theta$. This criterion can be calculated using the law of total expectation (smoothing theorem).

Answer (score 0):

Normally, $a$ should be a random variable. Otherwise it would not make sense to perform the estimation. So, the definition remains $B(\hat{a})=E(\hat{a})-a$. Here, $a$ is a specific realization. You can get a different bias for each realization of $a$. An estimator is called unbiased, if its bias is zero for all possible realizations of $a$.

Comment: what you wrote is incorrect. In a Bayesian estimation framework, $a$ would be a random variable, otherwise (which is most often the case) $a$ is an unknown deterministic parameter.

Comment: I agree and I believe your answer is more accurate and with more scope  than my attempt.